# Should bower_components be publicly accessible to get the benefit of sourcemaps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bower, source-maps

I use [Bower](http://bower.io) to manage dependencies in the form of Sass and JavaScript libraries. In almost all cases I reference these libraries directly from my Sass, CoffeeScript and JavaScript.

My build process concatenates and compresses the resultant assets. These combined stylesheets and JavaScripts also have sourcemaps. With the Bower-managed libraries coming straight from the bower_components directory, the sourcemaps create a dependency on having the bower_components directory publicly available.

When considering Bower alone, it's obvious that bower_components should be ignored by version control and referenced directly, but when adding the sourcemap aspect it starts to get a little blurry for me.

On the particular project I'm working on now I check compiled assets into version control to avoid having to compile them on Heroku. This might even try to force me to check the whole bower_components directory in. Yuck.

Thanks in advance if anyone has advice.